# how to use gcc instrumentation options without a native filesystem

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, instrumentation, cortex-m

Many of the [instrumentation options for gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#Instrumentation-Options) save data to a file during/after runtime:

> When the compiled program exits it **saves this data to a file** called auxname.gcda for each source file.

However, I'm running on a custom C++-based RTOS which doesn't have a filesystem "natively" like Linux.

**QUESTION**

How do I use these gcc-instrumentation options that output results to a file?
Do I have to provide a file-writer interface - which in my case would write to a RAM buffer - which would be called whenever the instrumentation code needs to "write to file"?

Comment: A web search for "gcc gprof arm-cortex-m" produces: https://mcuoneclipse.com/2015/08/23/tutorial-using-gnu-profiling-gprof-with-arm-cortex-m/ It appears to use semihosting to write profiling data to host machine. Does this help?

Comment: @domen yes that's the answer. Add it as the answer to this question so I can close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web search for "gcc gprof arm-cortex-m" produces: https://mcuoneclipse.com/2015/08/23/tutorial-using-gnu-profiling-gprof-with-arm-cortex-m/

It appears to use `semihosting` to write profiling data to host machine.

Semihosting is a common way for ARM to communicate with debugger on host (through JTAG/SWD). It is also supported on emulators like qemu.